# org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0) How to resolve it?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am facing this issue from past few days after adding google maps api in project. I have done everything , I have enabled the free trial billing and have also done many changes regarding code but nothing i got ,  after that i added google place api but result is the search bar suddenly disappear.

In this code it is showing error:

```html
private void drawRoute(final LatLng yourLocation, String address) {
        mService.getGeoCode(address).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

                    String lat=  ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results"))
                            .getJSONObject(0)
                            .getJSONObject("geometry")
                            .getJSONObject("location")
                            .get("lat").toString();

                    String lng=  ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results"))
                            .getJSONObject(0)
                            .getJSONObject("geometry")
                            .getJSONObject("location")
                            .get("lng").toString();

                    LatLng orderLocation=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng));

                    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.locationmarker);
                    bitmap=Common.scaleBitmap(bitmap,70,70);

                    MarkerOptions marker=new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                            .title("Order of "+Common.currentRequest.getPhone())
                            .position(orderLocation);
                    mMap.addMarker(marker);

                    //draw route
                    mService.getDirections(yourLocation.latitude+","+yourLocation.longitude,
                            orderLocation.latitude+","+orderLocation.longitude)
                            .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                                    new ParserTask().execute(response.body().toString());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

                                }
                            });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error occurs at this place:

```
((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results"))
    .getJSONObject(0)
```

You have to consider the case that the `results` property contains just an empty array. To do so you might assign the `results` array to a variable, test for its length and if it's `0` do something else like returning immediately (doing nothing) or showing a message to the user.

```
JSONArray results = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results");
if (results.length() == 0) {
    // handle this case, for example
    return;
}

// There is at least one result
String lat= results
    .getJSONObject(0)
    .getJSONObject("geometry")
    ...
```

Comment: Actually the problem is in map . I made an e commerce app in which only the vendor location appear , route and order location not

Comment: The error in your question's title clearly indicates it's a problem with accessing a JSONArray at index 0 when the array has no elements.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: Get the exact location of the error from the stack trace. If it's directly in your code, fix it. If it's in foreign code, you are probably passing some invalid value to some function. For help, add information to your question.